# How to subscribe to an observable as side effect?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, side-effects

I have a method which calls a another service to play a stream url within a player. `playStream$()` returns some streaming data which should be returned from the `play$()` method as well. As a side effect while playing a stream, i want to send a heartbeat, triggered by an interval.

```js
play$(streamId: number, position?: number): Observable<Stream> {
  return this.playerService.playStream$(streamId, position)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => this.heartbeat$(streamId).subscribe())
    );
}
```

Since it's not a good practice to subscribe to another observable inside a `tap()` operator, i'm looking for a solution with `switchMap`, `mergeMap` oder similar. BUT: I'm not interested in the heartbeat's emitted value. I just need the `Stream` data, as soon `playStream$()` emits. The heartbeat is just a side effect, which could even fail. `heartbeat$()` has a `takeUntil` Operator who makes sure to unsubscribe from it if nessecairy.

I allready tried `mergeMap` and `switchMap` but with the effect, that the subscriber from `play$()` won't get the `Stream` data immediately.

What's the RxJS way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are better solutions to this issue. I'd suggest the following quick solution

1. Use `combineLatestWith` operator to trigger both the requests.
2. Use `startWith` operater to emit a notification from the `heartbeat$` observable and `switchMap` operator + `NEVER` to avoid emitting rest it's notifications. If a first value isn't emitted, `combineLatestWith` wouldn't emit. If remaining values are emitted, `playStream$` would emit it's previous values as false positives.
3. Use `map` operator to return only the `playStream$` emissions.

```js
import { timer, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { combineLatestWith, switchMap, takeUntil, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

private heartbeat$ = (streamId: any) = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
  switchMap((value) => 
    this.http.post('some url').pipe(
      switchMap(() => NEVER)
    )
  ),
  startWith(null),
  takeUntil(this.stopHeartbeat$)
);

play$(streamId: number, position?: number): Observable<Stream> {
  return this.playerService.playStream$(streamId, position).pipe(
    combineLatestWith(this.heartbeat$(streamId)),
    map([playStream, heartbeat] => playStream)
  );
}
```

Edit: Replace `filter(() => !value)` with `startWith` + `switchMap` + `NEVER` combo. If not, the subscriber would only get `playStream$` emissions after the `heartbeat$` has emitted it's first notification.

Edit 2: Remove `interval()` -> `timer()`. Made obsolete by the usage of `startWith` operator.